# How can I auto sync with a folder on the server to a folder on a Windows pc

Tags: windows, ftp, synchronization

I have a directory on my server, Ubuntu Linux, and it contains a bunch .csv files and is updated regularly, I need to be able to sync that folder with a folder on a local machine which is a Windows PC.

There's no problem connecting via FTP, filezilla, but it's the automation I need to work out out.

The files once downloaded are then screened for deliveries.

I can't seem to see anything of help online.

Comment: `I can't seem to see anything of help online`  That's the first sign you didn't spend any time searching.  Takes a second to find something.  http://superuser.com/questions/123052/keeping-local-windows-folder-in-sync-with-remote-ftp-folder-in-real-time

Comment: Must be the way I was wording it!

Answer (score 5):

In Windows you can use WinSCP instead of Filezilla, it have a option "Autosync" every time a specific files change on local computer.

You can download and read the documentation in the oficial website: 
https://winscp.net/eng/download.php